# Xamarin Android Edit Contact Intent

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use the built in Android Intents referenced [here](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) to have the user update a contact. However, currently upon calling my UpdateContact function, nothing happens and there are no errors in the log as I debug either. If I change it to StartActivityForResult, the result is cancelled. Any help is appreciated

Also, value of contactUri is: "content://com.android.contacts/data/4"

**MainActivity.cs:**

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
editIntent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(contactUri), ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentItemType);
editIntent.PutExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
activity.StartActivity(editIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may also be stuck, I finally got this working after tons of trial and error. Below is my Android code to make this function correctly as intended.

Note: contactId is a string containing a proper Uri. I got mine because I had the User select a contact using a different intent which returned that Uri as part of the data in the OnActivityResult. You could also query for this information using Xamarin.Mobile or Android cursors.

**Code:**

```cs
var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
Android.Net.Uri mUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(contactId);
// The Cursor that contains the Contact row
var mCursor = activity.ContentResolver.Query(mUri, null, null, null, null);
mCursor.MoveToFirst();
// The index of the lookup key column in the cursor
int mLookupKeyIndex;
// The index of the contact's _ID value
int mIdIndex;
// The lookup key from the Cursor
string mCurrentLookupKey;
// The _ID value from the Cursor
long mCurrentId;
// A content URI pointing to the contact
Android.Net.Uri mSelectedContactUri;

/*
 * Once the user has selected a contact to edit,
 * this gets the contact's lookup key and _ID values from the
 * cursor and creates the necessary URI.
 */
// Gets the lookup key column index
mLookupKeyIndex = mCursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.LookupKey);
// Gets the lookup key value
mCurrentLookupKey = mCursor.GetString(mLookupKeyIndex);
// Gets the _ID column index
mIdIndex = mCursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id);
mCurrentId = mCursor.GetLong(mIdIndex);
mSelectedContactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.GetLookupUri(mCurrentId, mCurrentLookupKey);

// Creates a new Intent to edit a contact
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
/*
 * Sets the contact URI to edit, and the data type that the
 * Intent must match
 */
editIntent.SetDataAndType(mSelectedContactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentItemType);
// Sets the special extended data for navigation
editIntent.PutExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
activity.StartActivity(editIntent);
```